# stored procedure to back up database delete and create back up if already exists

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure to back up database, if at that location back up already exists drop and create back up. How can I do that?

Also, my created simple script is showing error, I think having problem with single quotes. Please help.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_DB_BACKUP]
    
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    EXEC (' BACKUP DATABASE warehouse TO DISK = 'C:\Users\aakar\Documents\warehouse.BAK'  WITH PASSWORD = ''APPLE'' ')
END
GO
```

Comment: The `PASSWORD` option is discontinued in modern (supported) SQL Server versions. No need for dynamic SQL, just specify the `INIT` option to replace the backup file if it already exists: `BACKUP DATABASE warehouse TO DISK = 'C:\Users\aakar\Documents\warehouse.BAK' WITH INIT;`

Comment: I'd recommend **not** deleting and recreating the same backup file. What happens if your SQL Server suffers an unfortunate death while in the middle of a backup operation? You'll have no working backup from which to restore.

Comment: Doing backups correct is a hard task. Maybe you can use an existing solution: https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html